# Is it true that $x^3 + a_4 x + a_6$ is a perfect square 50% of the time?

Tags: elliptic-curves

Can it be said that

$$x^3 + a_4 x + a_6 \; (\text{mod}\,p)$$

is a perfect square half of the time?

Apparently it does not. Simulating the elliptic curve points $\text{mod}\,103217$ only $310$ of them are perfect squares.

```
>>> from gmpy2 import is_square
>>> P = 103217
>>> len(list(filter(is_square, map(eq, range(P))))) / P
0.0030033812259608397
```

Yet, reading from Trappe's "Introduction to Cryptography with Coding Theory" (page 356) it's said that

> Since $x^3 + a_4 x + a_6$ is a square half of the time, we have about $1/2^K$ chance of failure. (...)

Comment: Is `is_square` checking if your numbers are squares of *integers*, or squares of *residue classes* of integers (i.e., working mod $p$)? I'm not sure this resolves things, but I suspect it will.

Comment: @pjs36 I guess that it checks if they're squares of integers. Indeed, implementing that function as `def is_square(x): return ceil(sqrt(x)) ** 2 == x` yield the same result - i.e. $.3\%$

Comment: But Trappe means "$x^3+a_4x+a_6$ is a square modulo $p$" - that is, there is some $k$ such that $x^3-a_4x+a_6-k^2$ is divisible by $p$.

Comment: Yeah, since the book mentions the polynomial is evaluated mod $p$, I'm guessing it means *square* in this sense (e.g. $4^2 = 16 \equiv 5 \pmod {11}$, so if $p = 11$, we'd say $5$ is a square). I'm not sure if any libraries have functions for determining if something is a *quadratic residue*, but that's what you're looking for (I suspect). I know Sage has [this functionality](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/constructions/number_theory.html)

Comment: If $p$ is prime, then about half of the finite field elements are quadratic residue ($y$ is a quadratic residue if $\exists x ~ x^2 \equiv y \pmod p$).  If $a_6$ ranges uniformly over $0 \dots p - 1$, then $\dots+a_6$ will have a 50% chance of being a quadratic residue.

Comment: If $x^3+a_4x+a_6$ is a "permutation polynomial" [see this ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_polynomial), as approx. the half of the elements of $\mathbb{Z_p}$ are squares, the work is done.